# Send text message to WhatsApp and SMS using intent create chooser not working anymore

Tags: android, sms, whatsapp

The code below used to work a week ago. It's purpose is to allow the user to choose if he want to send a text message using WhatsApp or SMS, but now when I choose WhatsApp it doesn't do anything, although SMS keeps working.

Looking at the logcat it's printing: `2018-10-25 18:28:28.915 2147-6714/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=smsto:xxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.whatsapp/.Conversation (has extras)} from uid 10096` Even passing a valid number with country code, it is printing `smsto:xxxxxxxxxxx`.

Is there any working code for this purpose or know about this problem?

```
fun sendMessageToNumber(number: String, text: String) {
    val cleanNumber = number.cleanText()
    val uri = Uri.parse("smsto:$cleanNumber")
    val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri)
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", text)
    context?.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, context.getString(R.string.fragment_account_chooser_message_title)))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of my project I have used following code for sending whatsapp message :

```
fun sendWhatsappMsg(){
            var toNumber = "+91 xxxxx xxxxx" // contains spaces.
            toNumber = toNumber.replace("+", "").replace(" ", "")

            val sendIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN")
            sendIntent.putExtra("jid", "$toNumber@s.whatsapp.net")
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello")
            sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
            sendIntent.type = "text/plain"
            startActivity(sendIntent)
}
```

And to send text message I have used following code :

```
fun sendTextMsg(){
           val phone = "xxxxxxxxxx"
           val msg = "smsto:" + phone
           val smsUri = Uri.parse(msg)
           val smsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, smsUri)
           startActivity(smsIntent)
}
```

You can try this. Both are working for me.